# pn532 card emulation mode and pn532 virtual card mode

Tags: nfc

### pn532 card emulation mode

I want to konw pn532 card emultion . I success running "iso 14443-4A emulation mode" but it have not block data like mifare card  . How can i make block data ? what frame is run "mifare classic card mode" . And in virtual card mode in samconfiguration , how can i get sam ( secure access module)?.
I have arduino mega adk , and nfc shield v1.0 ( pn532) . In this situation , how can i connect "sam" to nfc shield (pn532 )? . please help me .

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if configured properly the PN532 can perform card emulation with a smart card that is compatible with SWP/HCI protocol (single wire connection, ETSI TS 102 603, 102 622).

If you can get a sample test card that supports this protocol, and for which you know the keys, then you could do APDU (ISO 14443-4) card emulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PN532 as a NFC tag 4 card which can contain a NDEF message (block data?). If you use Arduino, https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/PN532 is for you.